# Using exp101 and log101 functions in C

Tags: c, math, exponential

I am trying to use the function exp1 and log101 which take long doubles as input and output long doubles in turn. However, when I try to compile the file I get the following error message:

```
/tmp/ccIvBVbG.o: In function `main':
derivative.c:(.text+0x250): undefined reference to `log101'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have included math.h library and also provided the -lm option. What is the remedy to this issue? Any help and comments are appreciated.

Thanks

P.S. Compiler is GCC on 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: Have you given any thought about the naming of these functions? Why are they called `exp101` and `log101`? These work with, as you say, "long doubles", and they are about powers of 10. Hint enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The names of the functions you are trying to use are `exp10l` and `log10l`.  The last character in the name is a lowercase L, *not* another 1.